# IIS logging of events before Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 website running on IIS 7.5 that takes a lot of time to start.
I have a hunch that it is because of a lot of DLL's in the bin folder.

I have tried Red Gate's ANTS Performance profiler but I only get messages like "JIT overhead" and not specifics about which files takes time to load.

Is there some way of logging how long the different DLL's take to load?

What I need is some kind of log like:

```
a.dll - 123 ms
b.dll - 234 ms
```

and so on..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is not the dlls, nether you can count that time you ask. What you should look is, do you have many files on the `App_Code`, and if you run many time consumed initialize functions. Also you can look at the web.config for the compiler settings, to set less files for batch compile. One more. You can use ProcessExplorer to see if the time is for compile or for running code.